# Static version pub/static/versionxxxx increases everytime I load the page

Tags: magento2, php, static-content-deploy

When I do **static:deploy**, the version text file is written in `pub/static`. 
When I repeatedly load the website and look at the source, the version number on the link is growing each time.

I checked the processes and nothing is running. It's probably not in a **rebuild loop** because text file in `pub/static` stays the same. But the browser request has the version incremented every second. If I wait a bit between the request, like for example 30 seconds, the version will have **incremented roughly about 30**.

Comment: Update: Apparently it is in a rebuild loop, I edited and uploaded a less file, when I refreshed the page the changes were already there. Without me rebuilding or doing anything else besides moving the modified less file to the server. I kinda like it actually : ) But I need to find a way to shut it off eventually...

Comment: there is no grunt, no triggers, nothing watching the folder etc....